# "Please correct before proceeding." - Web.config error

Tags: visual-studio

I attempted to launch a website project locally but received the below message in an error dialog:

> Please correct before proceeding.(You might rename the current web.config and add a new one).

Typically this error is preceded by a general description of the cause, this one was not.  Knowing odd, out-of-the-blue, problems such as these are typically related to corrupt IDE generated files. I tried deleting the `.suo`, `.vssscc` and other generated files from the solution and project directories but the problem continued.

Comment: 8 years later and this stupidly obscure message is still a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the problem using a solution I found for a different IDE-related issue (original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892460/visual-studio-page-not-found/21892485#21892485)).  Run the following in an elevated command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup
```

**Note:** You'll need to adjust the path for your version of Visual Studio (original version mapping answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/194058/what-does-the-number-on-the-visual-studio-solution-icon-represent)):

- Visual Studio 2005 = 8
- Visual Studio 2008 = 9.0
- Visual Studio 2010 = 10.0
- Visual Studio 2012 = 11.0
- Visual Studio 2013 = 12.0
- Visual Studio 2015 = 14.0

Comment: In the start menu, there is `Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual Studio Tools`. Open it and select `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015`. This will open a console with the right entry directory, so you can type `devenv.exe /setup` directly. A similar entry exists for the older Visual Studio versions.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but I had to close Visual Studio before running an elevated Developer Command Prompt and once it was done start Visual Studio again. Running it while having Visual Studio 2019 open did not help.

Answer (score 91):

This happened to me today after getting latest.  I resolved by closing and reopening the solution, rebuild, then run.  All is well...

Comment: Except that you had to do that.

Comment: Mine requires restarting visual studio... Closing and opening the solution isn't even good enough for me. *frowny face* Gotta be some hung process in IIS or something?

Comment: After closing all .config file visualisation also worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

I actually resolved this by making sure the Web.config file wasn't an open document inside VS 2015.  In other words, close the Web.config file wherever it might be open, and make sure your Team Explorer isn't causing any problems, like an unexpected change or staged change...rebuild the sln and run...

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution which is so much easier/quicker than close/reopen VS

Answer (score 23):

Close vs2017 and open it again worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.9.0

Comment: the best solution is to reboot visual studio all for versions

Answer (score 15):

just open web.config and run again.I've had this problem and I resolved by this solution .

Comment: altough it's a temporary soulution :)

Answer (score 6):

This issue came to me after merging some code in version control using RTC tools. When I saw [whyoz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251964/2944723) I noticed that web.config wasn't opened anywhere. It could be RTC locking the file or something like this. So, I simply restarted Visual Studio and it became normal again.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today after doing a branch merge using the VS19 built-in Git tools.  The config file was correct; I even used a schema validator based on KD2ND's answer in [how can I validate dot net application config file(ex, app.exe.config) on console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084154/how-can-i-validate-dot-net-application-config-fileex-app-exe-config-on-consol).

I cleaned the solution, unloaded it, and reloaded it, and everything worked fine.  I didn't even need to restart studio.

Based on others' answers, this appears to be related to code merging in the IDE. It's a weird problem but it's a relief that the solution (once found) is simple.

Answer (score 3):

As an FYI, in VS 2019 the solution is to close the tabs, and the solution and Visual Studio, then restart Visual Studio. This has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 : Just neeed to close project, thenn open+ clean+rebuild and everything work

Answer (score 1):

In VS 19 Enterprise, the Solution for me was:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup
```

Based on the merked answer from alan.

Answer (score 1):

I had just opened the web.config file and then pressed CTRL K + D. it will make the formatting good of the file. and then run the application. it worked for me.

Even if you undo the above changes then also it works. it is weird somehow.

Comment: editing web.config will recycle application pool usually. so that might be the real fix

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how or why, but in my case, just opening the web.config file in visual studio , are solving my problem... if i close the web.config file in visual studio, the error message appears.